Swift Combine: Preventing memory leaks with coordinator pattern and subscription management
I'm trying to use Combine instead of delegates while implementing the Coordinator pattern. However, when I remove a coordinator from the childCoordinators list, it causes a memory leak. How can I ensure that the coordinator is automatically deallocated? Specifically, I want the coordinator.actions.sink subscription to be properly terminated and the coordinator to be cleaned up from memory.
// MARK: - BaseCoordinator
@MainActor
class BaseCoordinator: Coordinator {
    let navigator: NavigatorType
    var childCoordinators: [Coordinator] = []
    var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    init(navigator: NavigatorType) {
        self.navigator = navigator
    }

    func start() {
        // Default implementation, can be overridden by subclasses
    }
}


// MARK: - ExampleFlowCoordinator
final class ExampleFlowCoordinator: BaseCoordinator {
    override func start() {
        let coordinator = ExampleCoordinator()
        add(coordinator)
        coordinator.actions.sink { [weak self] action in
            guard let self else { return }
            switch action {
            case .done:
                remove(coordinator)
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)

        navigator.setRootViewController(coordinator.rootViewController, animated: true)

        coordinator.start()
    }

    private func showExample2() {
        let coordinator = ExampleCoordinator2()

        coordinator.actions.sink { [weak self] action in
            guard let self else { return }
            switch action {
            case .done:
                remove(coordinator)
            }
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)

        add(coordinator)
        coordinator.start()
        navigator.present(coordinator.rootViewController, animated: true) { [weak self] in
            guard let self else { return }
            remove(coordinator)
        }
    }
}

In the showExample2() function, when remove(coordinator) is executed, the coordinator is successfully removed from childCoordinators. However, due to coordinator.actions.sink, the coordinator continues to live in memory (if I remove this part, it works successfully).

"However, due to coordinator.actions.sink, the coordinator continues to live in memory (if I remove this part, it works successfully)." Indeed. When you remove the coordinator, you also need to remove its sink from cancellables. The whole point of cancellables is to keep its pipelines alive. Hence the leak.

@matt I actually wrote this to confirm that the memory leak was entirely related to this sink function.

So you've answered your own question. If not, what is the question?

To solve it, you might want to give each Coordinator a unique ID. Then, use a dictionary [ID: AnyCancellable] to store your subscriptions. When the coordinator is done, remove the cancellable by id.
By the way, always ensure your class checks invariants! For example, start() must be called once and only once. These are potential bugs, which can occur far too often.

The solution here is to get rid of the childCoordinators: [Coordinator] array. The Combine system will ensure that any resources in the coordinator that need to be retained will be retained.
When it's time to shutdown a coordinator, either the parent coordinator can cancel the appropriate cancellable(s), or the child coordinator can send a completion event.
